# Set fetch all option in limit parameter if the field is empty

Tags: php

For my function I want to set 2 parameters like the ones below, and only set the limit for the query if the user wants to use that parameter.

```
public function getNewsByCatId($id, $limit){

    $args = array(
        'fields' => array(
                    'news.id', 
                    'news.title',  
                    'news.story', 
                    'news.image',
                    'news.status',
                    'news.added_date',
                    'categories.title AS news_category',
                    '(SELECT users.full_name FROM users WHERE id = news.added_by) as author',
                ),
        'where' => array(
            'news_category' => $id 
        ),
        'join'  => 'LEFT JOIN categories on news.news_category = categories.id',
       'limit' => array(0, $limit);
    );

    return $this->select($args);

}
```

What should be set as a default parameter value if I don't pass a value of limit in function? Can I use `if else` condition inside the function? Example:

```
 public function getNewsByCatId($id, $limit){

    $args = array(
        'fields' => array(
                    'news.id', 
                    'news.title',  
                    'news.story', 
                    'news.image',
                    'news.status',
                    'news.added_date',
                    'categories.title AS news_category',
                    '(SELECT users.full_name FROM users WHERE id = news.added_by) as author',
                ),
        'where' => array(
            'news_category' => $id 
        ),
        'join'  => 'LEFT JOIN categories on news.news_category = categories.id',
    );

    if ($limit > 0) {
          //condition to be applied
       } else {
   //condition to be applied
    }

    return $this->select($args);

    }
```

Comment: Whatever you want. You can choose a default limit, you can make the limit entirely optional and decide not to use it if not passed... Do you have an actual issue, or you just need someone to tell you how to complete this script?

Comment: @yivi I want to fetch all rows if nothing is passed in parameter. I tried doing `$limit = 0` but that did not help

Comment: Just do not set the `'limit'` if the user passes 0 or null. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy does it:

```php
public function getNewsByCatId(int $id, ?int $limit = 10) {

   $args = [
      // your original argument definition
      // do NOT SET LIMIT HERE
   ];

   if ($limit !== null && $limit > 0) {
      $args['limit'] = [0, $limit];
   }

   return $this->select($args);

}
```

I've formatted the code for modern PHP. If your PHP version does not support type hinting, short array declarations, etc, change the code (or better yet, consider upgrading your PHP engine).

This way you have default `$limit` clients can use, or they can pass `null` (or an integer <= 0) to disable the limit altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a default value to `$limit` variable in function definition. If `$limit` has default value that means, it is not set and you can avoid applying limit condition in your query array. Check below code:

```
function getNewsByCatId($id, $limit = false){

    $args = array(
        'fields' => array('news.id', 'news.title', 'news.story', 'news.image', 'news.status', 'news.added_date',
            'categories.title AS news_category', '(SELECT users.full_name FROM users WHERE id = news.added_by) as author'),

        'where' => array(
            'news_category' => $id 
        ),

        'join'  => 'LEFT JOIN categories on news.news_category = categories.id',
    );
    if ($limit && $limit > 0 && is_numeric($limit)) { /* Only applying limit condition if you some value in it.*/
        $args['limit'] = array(0, $limit);
    }
    return $this->select($args);
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Set default value for second parameter to null. And add some condition in your function.

```
public function getNewsByCatId($id, $limit=NULL){

    // Your code

    if($limit){
        // Your code            
    }

 }
```